# How to push object to observable using subscribe?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

i have emitter sending data from another component that i was able to print in constructor, Now trying to push that `e` to `data` it is throw error `push is undefined`.
what is correct approach to subscribe and push data to array ?

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {JsonEditorOptions } from 'ang-jsoneditor';
import { EventService } from './format-questions.service'
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-format-questions',
  templateUrl: './format-questions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./format-questions.component.css']
})
export class FormatQuestionsComponent implements OnInit {


  public editorOptions: JsonEditorOptions;
  data: any = [];
  subscription: Subscription;
  @ViewChild(JsonEditorComponent, { static: true }) editor: JsonEditorComponent;

  constructor(private event: EventService) { 
    this.editorOptions = new JsonEditorOptions()
    this.editorOptions.modes = ['code', 'text', 'tree', 'view'];
    this.subscription = event.dataAnnounced$.subscribe(
      e => {
        this.data.push(e);
        console.log("event from appComp", e);
      });
  }

    ngOnInit() { 
  }


}
```

Comment: **push is undefined** or **cannot read property push of undefined** ? , Make sure you are not resetting the **this.data** to `undefined` or `null` anywhere. Also 
 [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) will be very helpful to us for debugging

Comment: @sameer Khan all the code i have added in the question

Comment: IMO, there might be `this` issue refrence? 
I tried to mimic fetch call using fake api and tried to push it in `this.data` and it is seems to work. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vxk9e3